# svn add trunk/* not working

Tags: wordpress, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN-1.9.7 and trying to upload my plugin files to wordpress svn of my plugin.

I'm on this folder:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\dotorg
```

And then:

```
svn add trunk/*
```

I got this in return:

```
svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\dotorg' was not found.
svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\dotorg' was not found.
svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\dotorg' was not found.
svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\dotorg' was not found.
svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\dotorg' was not found.
svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\dotorg' was not found.
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

It doesn't make sense! I'm on the dotorg folder which has a trunk folder with my plugin files, also the `https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-plugin/` url shows me there is a `trunk` folder. So what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try following commands**:

```
svn cleanup
svn cleanup *
svn cleanup dotorg
svn add --force dotorg
svn commit
```

If it still **doesn't work then try this**:

```
rm -rf dotorg/.svn
svn add dotorg
svn commit
```